# How to use HighChart in offline?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i am downloaded highchart javascript and create a sample chart using these script.
this chart is displayed if system is online or other wise not..

Thanks advance

Answer (score 3):

Probably, if you followed the instructions in Highcharts web page, you will have something like:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you download the [jquery library](http://jquery.com/download/) into your computer, you will be capable of using highcharts offline.

Comment: thanks,now i have highchart library.<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> if the above script is worked,if system is online

Comment: Go to http://jquery.com/download/ and download the library in your computer.

Comment: thanks now i have jquery library.The chart is displayed superb.

Comment: @MadasamySankarapandian Can u share your code for offline use.Please help me.I am also trying to use highchart for offline use,but i don't know how to use this.